# Echo new lines and unescaped values in textarea during Post Redirect Get routine

Tags: php, html, mysql-real-escape-string

Trying to keep new lines and unescaped values intact in a textarea being repopulated with data during a PRG cycle. At what point do you assign the variable correctly so that new lines are recognized?

I've tried double quotes, `nl2br`, `htmlentities`, `stripslashes` but I can't seem to get it. Some attempts:

Assigning during the intial prg `$_SESSION` array:

```
$_SESSION['prg']['textarea'] = "$textarea";
```

When passing from prg array to var:

```
$textarea = htmlentities($_SESSION['prg']['textarea']);
```

When echoing into the textarea:

```
<textarea name="textarea"><?php if(isset($textarea)) echo nl2br($textarea); ?></textarea>
```

And various combinations of the above, including the initial `$_POST`, directly after sanitizing.

Also, in case anyone asks: the escaping works as intended, db insert results are fine. It's just the form repopulating that's throwing things off.

I'm sure this is just a symptom of amateur hour... Looking for php/html solution only. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to be calling `nl2br` when you populate the text area if you want to keep the newlines showing up properly in the textarea.  The `htmlentities` part is good though.

Answer (score 0):

while storing the data use `addslashes($_POST['textarea'])` and while displaying use `stripslashes($textarea)`